# Jquery Validation for text box valuess

Tags: jquery

How to validate Text box values using Regular Expression For example Validating the Email, Phone number, String Values

Comment: Already Lot of jquery plugins available in web, It may fulfill your need

Comment: Way too unspecific. Give specific questions, with code examples, that show you put more effort into trying to figure out this question than typing 60 characters into your keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this jquery http://jqueryvalidation.org/

This jQuery plugin makes simple clientside form validation easy

[DEMO](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/)

**or**

**Email Validation:**

```
    <script type = "text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        function ValidateEmail(email) {
            var expr = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
            return expr.test(email);
        };
        $("#demo").live("click", function () {
            if (!ValidateEmail($("#txtEmail").val())) {
                alert("Invalid email address.");
            }
            else {
                alert("Valid email address.");
            }
        });
    </script>
    <input type = "text" id = "txtEmail" />
<input type = "button" id = "demo" value = "Demo" />
```

**for numeric characters**

```
$('.keyup-numeric').keyup(function() {
    $('span.error-keyup-1').hide();
    var inputVal = $(this).val();
    var numericReg = /^\d*[0-9](|.\d*[0-9]|,\d*[0-9])?$/;
    if(!numericReg.test(inputVal)) {
        $(this).after('<span class="error error-keyup-1">Numeric characters only.</span>');
    }
});
```

Comment: i need validation code and regular expresions

Comment: Sorry friend Now only i got 15 reputation